# How to open pdf file in wicked_pdf?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, plugins, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

Right now im using rail 3.0.0 version.now im generate the pdf file and save that file in public folder using wicked_pdf.now i want open that pdf file using controller action.Im using this code in controller.but it is not working.please help me how to do.

```
         def download_prescription_pdf 
            pdf_pres = UploadedDocument.find(params[:pdf]) 
            send_file "#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/prescription/#{pdf_pres.file_path}", :type => "application/pdf" 
         end
```

Comment: Does the file exist at the path your are looking for it? How is it not working?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
        render :template  => 'admin/idreport',
               :formats => [:pdf],
               :handlers => [:erb],
               :pdf => "ID List",
               :save_to_file => Rails.root.join('../Documents', "ID List")
```

Good Luck

Bob